# Problem with three-level hierarchical regression using lmer

Tags: r, lme4-nlme

I'm trying to run a 3 level hierarchical regression in lmer in R.
The model is specified:

```
model <- lmer(dependent ~ ind1 + ... + (1|level3/level2), data=data)
```

However, when I enter this code, R starts processing it for 20 minutes and doesn't respond. Am I doing something incorrectly?

Comment: What you've done is create a factor that is the product of `level3` and `level2` and (based on your comment that it's taking 20+ minutes to run), this product factor has _many_ levels, many of which probably only have a couple of observations in them. So, the model is having a hard time estimating this random effect variance. Is this what you meant to do?